# speed_kph imputed by osmnx.speed.add_edge_speeds is not constant given highway type, inconsistent with OSMnx documentation

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am using osmnx.speed.add_edge_speeds to impute free-flow travel speeds for all edges. According to OSMnx manual on https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-reference.html#osmnx.speed.add_edge_speeds, "this imputes free-flow travel speeds for all edges via the mean maxspeed value of the edges of each highway type". This implies that the imputed "speed_kph" attribute should have the same value for edges with the same highway. However, my results are inconsistent with this implication.

My codes are as follows.

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from pandas import Series, DataFrame


cf = '["highway"~"motorway"]'
G = ox.graph_from_place("Los Angeles County, California, USA", network_type="drive", custom_filter=cf)



G = ox.speed.add_edge_speeds(G)
gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False)

#the following two lines of codes are borrowed from 
#https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/main/notebooks/02-routing-speed-time.ipynb 
#to compute mean speed values by road type 

gdf_edges["highway"] = gdf_edges["highway"].astype(str)
gdf_edges.groupby("highway")[["length", "speed_kph"]].mean().round(1)
df=pd.DataFrame(gdf_edges).reset_index()
df = df[['u','v','ref','highway','speed_kph']][1:15]
```

The following is the output:
[image]

You can see that mean speed is different within motorways: some are 88.5, some are 104.6, and some are 101.6, while the mean speed for motorway should be 101.6, as computed.

I am curious why this would happen. Any comments will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It only imputes speed on edges missing OSM speed attribute values. So the mean across some highway type will be a function of what values were present on OSM and what values were imputed when missing.